# Pior que; menos bom que; não tão bom como. São equivalentes?

Tags: significado, grau-comparativo

Imaginemos dois restaurantes, *O Lambão* e o *À Fartazana*. Quais seriam as diferenças, se é que as existem, entre:

> *O Lambão* é pior que o *À Fartazana*;
>
> *O Lambão* é menos bom que o *À Fartazana*;
>
> *O Lambão* não é tão bom como o *À Fartazana*?

Comment: O _pior_ soa sempre pior que os restantes... No entanto, para lambões, à fartazana será sempre melhor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todas as frases significam que a qualidade d'*O Lambão* é inferior à do *À Fartazana*.

Dependendo do contexto, "é pior" pode ter uma implicação de que a qualidade de ambos é baixa (afinal de contas, "pior" é o comparativo de superioridade de "mau"), mas a forma mais explícita para exprimir essa ideia é usar "ainda pior":

> *O Lambão* é **ainda pior** que o *À Fartazana*.

Uma forma mais neutra de dizer que a qualidade do *À Fartazana* é mais alta do que a d'*O Lambão* é:

> O *À Fartazana* é melhor do que *O Lambão*.

Mas esta frase põe o foco no *À Fartazana*, não n'*O Lambão*.

A frase com "menos bom" é a que soa menos natural das três. Parece uma forma pouco idiomática de evitar a possível conotação negativa de "pior". Existe uma implicação de que a qualidade do *À Fartazana* é, se não alta, pelo menos não baixa.

A terceira frase, com *não é tão bom*, é já mais idiomática. O significado é semelhante a *menos bom*, mas talvez com uma implicação mais forte de que o *À Fartaza* é bom em termos absolutos.

Também podemos fazer uma distinção no que toca ao tamanho da diferença de qualidade. A primeira sugere uma diferença maior do que as restantes (especialmente do que a última, que literalmente apenas se limita a negar que sejam equivalentes em termos de qualidade).

Answer (score 1):

No Brasil **"menos bom"** seria, no mínimo, unusual.  Eu não usaria essa forma gramatical.

"O Lambão é pior que o À Fartazana" está correto. "O Lambão" pode ser ***pior*** ou ***muito pior***.  Dá a impressão que o Lambão é ruim. O "À Fartazana" pode não o ser.

"O lambão **não é tão bom quanto** o "À Fartazana", ambos podem ser bons, ou até mesmo muito bons, mas **o "À Fartazana" é melhor.**

Mas temos outras opções para evitar ambiguidade: ***é bem melhor, é um pouco melhor, é melhor, é superior, é bem superior, é um pouco inferior, é muito inferior, etc.***