# Podemos dizer "menos pior"?

Tags: superlativos

Sempre achei que aqueles que trabalham na mídia, escrita ou falada, são indivíduos bem letrados e cuidadosos com o vernáculo. Ou pelo menos deveriam ser.  Ultimamente tenho ouvido o uso de "menos pior" em noticiários. Como eu não usaria tal expressão, fiquei então em dúvida se é correta ou não. O contexto foi o seguinte:

- Informamos que o trânsito está intenso pela Linha Vermelha. Na Avenida Brasil ele aparenta estar menos pior.

Ouvi também o uso em outras frases, e em outras emissoras, mas não recordo o contexto. **É correto esse uso? É aceitável na lingua falada, formal e informal?**

[Esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/pior-que-menos-bom-que-n%c3%a3o-t%c3%a3o-bom-como-s%c3%a3o-equivalentes) semelhante não aborda "menos pior".

Comment: Embora não esteja correto, hoje em dia o noticiário, principalmente no rádio, é repleto de coloquialismo. note que o coloquialismo em questão adiciona informação que a frase dita corretamente não traria: Que o trânsito na Av. Brasil também está péssimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, nessa frase não se pode dizer "menos pior"; deve-se dizer "menos mau".

Pior é comparativo de mau, como melhor é comparativo de bom.
Para o trânsito na segunda zona estar *mais pior* do que o da primeira, o da primeira tem de estar pior.
Mas pior é comparativo, e o trânsito da primeira foi descrito absolutamente (mau) - e não relativamente (pior).
Se não sabemos se o trânsito da primeira zona está pior do que alguma outra coisa (porque foi descrito sem comparação com nada), não podemos dizer que o trânsito da segunda zona está ainda pior (ou, possivelmente, menos pior).

O trânsito na Linha Vermelha está intenso. Mau.
O trânsito na Avenida Brasil aparenta estar menos intenso. Menos mau.
Portanto:

> Informamos que o trânsito está intenso pela Linha Vermelha. Na Avenida Brasil ele aparenta estar *menos mau*.

---

Mas mais ainda: porque "pior" é um superlativo, não pode levar "mais" nem "menos".

Sendo um superlativo:

> um adjetivo ou advérbio que indica **o mais alto grau** de significação.
> o mais alto grau de significação
>
> "superlativo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/superlativo [consultado em 27-10-2020].

Uma coisa ou é a mais-X, ou não o é.
Ou é a pior = mais-má, número 1 no pódio de ser-mau, ou não.
Não pode ser "mais primeiro lugar" ou "menos primeiro lugar".

Comment: Mas, claro, o português é uma língua muito traiçoeira... Se fizermos por exemplo uma lista dos investimentos financeiros de cada indivíduo, podemos analisar o pior investimento de cada um dos indivíduos e tentar perceber subjetivamente dentre esses piores investimentos de cada um, qual é *o mais ou o menos pior*. Um que perdeu 2 milhões = 70%, ou um que perdeu 3 milhões = 50%?

Comment: Quase sempre, *dá* para construir artificialmente uma exceção a uma regra "não se pode usar".

Comment: Concordo, especialmente usando trapaças como a frase 'Podemos dizer “menos pior”?' :)

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Não entendi o seu primeiro comentário.

Comment: @Centaurus, estava a tentar referir que há quase sempre maneiras excecionais de usar coisas que normalmente não se podem usar. Mas não consegui, é muito cedo...